# How do I make several different edit/update views for a model while maintaining rest? (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have a model "Voyage" which needs several different types of forms.

There is an arrival form, departure form, check-in form, etc.

Currently I have this implemented by creating new actions in my controller, such as

```
    def arrival_form
    ...
    end

    def departure_form
    ...
    end
```

All of these are basically edit/update actions though.

I feel like there probably is a better, cleaner way to do it but I just haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: They are loaded dynamically, right?

Comment: Yes they are. It might not be as big of an issue as I'm making them out to be. I could certainly just use javascript and replace a container in my the view, but I wanted something cleaner. On that topic...maybe there is a way to link to the Javascript and call for a certain partial like edit_voyage(@voyage, :load_partial_with_name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly can render your form by choosing generic view like that:

```
def edit
  # logic omitted
  render "#{params[:state]}_form" if Voyage::STATES.include? params[:state]
end
```

Or if your forms is some kind of step_by_step wizard you could use @voyage.state in form generation. I think you get the idea.
And you should update your `Voyage` instances with `update` action just fine.